# Find top Stack Overflow users by their technology stack and location

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, top-users

How to find top Stack Overflow users by their technology stack and location?

Comment: Recruiters don't (and shouldn't) use SEDE, they have proper channels, which also gives money to SE as it should. Bypassing this harms SE in general.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've deleted the second statement. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

#### [Top SO users by tech stack (tags score) and location](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/792711/top-so-users-by-tech-stack-tags-score-and-location)

**Usage example**:

> find experts in REST, Spring, Spring frameworks and Hibernate related projects from Ukraine, with minimum Stack Overflow reputation of 1000

```
Tags:            rest, spring
Tag masks:       spring-, hibernate-
Location masks:  Ukraine
Min. reputation: 1000
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]

**Clarifications**:

- Tags are comma-separated Stack Overflow [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
- Tag mask here is the beginning part of the tag name. There are a lot of tags
  related to the one main technology and started identically with a dash, 
  for example: `spring-boot`, `spring-data`, `spring-data-jpa` - all those
  tags have tag mask `spring-`.

  So if you want to find experts in Spring only - you should type `spring` in the field **Tags**. But if you need to find experts in Spring and related frameworks as well, you should type `spring` in **Tags** and `spring-` in **Tag masks**.
- Location masks are arbitrary parts of the user location separated by a comma, for example, `Odessa, Odesa` or `Kiev, Kyiv` etc.
- Min. reputation is a minimum reputation of Stack Overflow user who will get in the selection.